# discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: NameError

Tags: discord.py

I was using cogs on discord.py to detach the file, but there was a bug that caused NameError and was not running. How can I solve this?

Error

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'cogs.news' raised an error: NameError: name 'news' is not defined.
```

app.py

```py
...
# Cogs Part
extension = ["cogs.commands","cogs.news", "cogs.manage"]

for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
    if filename.endswith('.py'):
        client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')
...
```

cogs/news.py

```py
...
    class news(news.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(name='news')
    async def news(self, ctx):
    # ^^^ NameError : name 'news' is not defined


...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need any more help after reading this, you can join [this small discord server](https://discord.gg/4GKAjpG5w5).

I don't know if you left it out intentionally, but you need to add the following code at the end of the cogs/news.py file.

```
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(news(bot))
```

Also, you shouldn't need to load the extensions like you did, try doing this instead by removing the:

> extension = ["cogs.commands","cogs.news", "cogs.manage"]

Like so:

```
for file in os.listdir("./cogs"): 
    if file.endswith(".py"): 
        name = file[:-3] 
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{name}")
```

If none of this works consider replacing the

> class news(news.Cog):

With:

```
class news(commands.Cog):
```

**EXTRAS:**
You can also add a command on the app.py file that allows you to reload any command in the cogs without restarting the bot:

```
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def reload(ctx, *, name: str):
    try:
        client.reload_extension(f"cogs.{name}")
    except Exception as e:
        return await ctx.send(e)
    await ctx.send(f'"**{name}**" Cog reloaded')
```

And an option that alows you to disable or enable a command:

```
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def load(ctx, *, name: str):
    try:
        client.load_extension(f"cogs.{name}")
    except Exception as e:
        return await ctx.send(e)
    await ctx.send(f'"**{name}**" Cog loaded')
```

And

```
@client.command()
@commands.is_owner()
async def unload(ctx, *, name: str):
    try:
        client.unload_extension(f"cogs.{name}")
    except Exception as e:
        return await ctx.send(e)
    await ctx.send(f'"**{name}**" Cog unloaded')
```

*If this help in any way, an upvote and a mark as answer would be appreciated :)*